# What should I use to get stats from other websites?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, analytics

I don't know my question title is correct or not but let me explain you what I want to do.

So I want to generate a script from my dashboard website(e.g dashboard.com) which user will put on his website's page(http://userwebsite.com/thankyou.php) and when any user visit that page I want to store the number of visits of that page on my dashboard website(http://dashboard.com).

Currently I am using **XMLHttpRequest** . So I generate a script which has the code of Ajax and that ajax hits a post request on my dashboard website(I am using some token for a particular script).

I am not sure this is the right way or not to achieve my goal.I am sure you guys have seen these kind of scripts. There are so many websites (most popular Google Analytics).

Please help me what should I do for it, or it's fine to use ajax?

Thanks.

Comment: AJAX is the way to do it. I'm pretty sure that's what Google Analytics does.

Comment: You can achieve this purely server side if you want

Comment: @Barmar and what about if user has disabled Javascript and what will happen in case of CORS?

Comment: You won't get stats if the user disables Javascript. CORS is controlled by the site that receives the AJAX request, so you can deal with it at your end.

Comment: GA has the same problem. There aren't so many users who disable Javascript that it makes a significant impact on statistics.

Comment: @Barmar okay thanks for the help. I think I am on right track of using javascript and xmlhttpRequest.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a common choice for that type of thing, so you're on the right track with Ajax. One of the advantages to the JavaScript approach is that it's simple for other users to add it on a site.

With your script, you can add options for naming the page, or recording certain actions, etc. You may have an issue if a user has disabled JavaScript, but that tends to be a small number of users these days.

I will say that I see GET requests used more often for that type of thing.

Comment: what about if user has disabled Javascript and what will happen in case of CORS?

Comment: When JavaScript is disabled, you may be more limited in your options for logging analytics, but you can probably record a pageview by settings up an image request that includes some querystring parameters in the URL, and then whichever server handles that image request can log the analytics for you. 

if it's a CORS situation, you may have difficulty if you don't control whether it's allowed. You might be able to work around it by setting up a handler on your server that can serve as a proxy, and essentially deliver that foreign origin script like it is originating from your site.